# Can't connect to mysql 127.0.0.1 but can connect on localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost, privileges, sql-grant

```
C:\Users\dp\Desktop>mysql -u user -pXXXX -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mywayuser'@'localhost' (using passwo
rd: YES)

C:\Users\dp\Desktop>mysql -u user -pXXXX -h localhost -P 3306
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 14
Server version: 5.6.21-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> exit
```

I've already GRANTED ALL PRIVILEGES for 127.0.0.1 .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`user@localhost` and `user@127.0.0.1` are different credentials in MySql.  For Mysql the host of `localhost` is basically "connect via socket, not an IP".

To connect explicity to localhost via socket as you're trying, you need to have an entry specifically for the desired user  at `localhost` in the mysql.user table:

```
 CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxx';
```

Even the catch all "%" won't work.  You must have a localhost entry if you wish to use it.  Then grant privileges to this user.

Or you could connect by using the ip `127.0.0.1` or any other hostname that maps to `127.0.0.1` other than the special host `localhost`

```
mysql -u user -pXXXX -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

Yep, I would have preferred if mysql didn't treat localhost like this, but there it is...

Comment: This was a big help to me after moving MarinaDB to another server.